# How can we add a bot when we are not the owner of the server?

Tags: discord.py, bots

I'm writing a bot for someone in python using Discord.py. Kindly share some knowledge regarding this issue.

Comment: did you consider using this new site called https://google.com?

Comment: Yeah ! I consider and all results were flooded with stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

To add a bot to a server you need to firstly have the "Manage Server" or "Administrator" permission in that server.
Then head to the Discord Developer Portal > Your Application > OAuth2 and click on the scopes you need ("Bot" is the one needed for bot commands although you will need "applications.commands" if you plan to use the new slash commands. It will generate a link that you (or someone else, if you have made it a public bot in the bot tab of the portal) can click on to add the bot to their server.

Comment: So in order to add bot to someone else's server firstly we should make a public bot then we need permission of the server's owner to add it to its server. Am i right ? If not then please clear my concepts as I am new in bots making.

Comment: Not necessarily the server owner - anyone with the "Manage Server" permission (or "Administrator", which gives all permissions) will be able to add the bot.

Answer (score 1):

A bot must be created. To do this, log into the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and see your applications there.

To make the whole thing a bot navigate in your application as followed:

```
Application - New Application - Bot - Add Bot
```

To add the necessary permissions I recommend the following page:
https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#

Here you will get a number spit out when you are done.
To add the bot you need the `Manage Server` or `Administrator` permission. The bot does not have to be public, because you as the owner can always add it, but not others if it is set to "Private".

The *invitation link* is/can be structured as followed:

https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ApplicationID&scope=bot&permissions=Permissions

Just add the `ApplicationID` *(You can find it in the Developer Portal of the application under "General Information")* and the permissions of Discord Permissions Calculator to the end.

***(Replace the words with your Application ID and the permission "code".)***

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this unless you selfbot, **however** this is against Discord's ToS and the account that you're using can get banned because Discord often checks for people who selfbot.